# jQuery - Scroll to div with no IDs and a button

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a gallery application where I show images a album has. When user comes to a album page, I have all images displayed *(from top to bottom)* and in top I have a **Next** button.

*Like image below:*

[image]

Because every album has different amount of images and are added dynamically, I can not add `ID`s and Want to have only **one** Next button.

As you can see Every image has a `divider`. How can I make it so when **Next button** is clicked, it scrolls/goes to next/nearest `divider`.

*Here is my code:*

```
<a href="#" id="next-button">Next</a>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="img-divider">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="img-divider">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="img-divider">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="img-divider">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="img-divider">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="img-divider">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>
```

Comment: HTML will be more useful than image

Comment: Our problem is we can not go to next unless you provide your code?

Comment: @Satpal Code added

Comment: @ScanQR Code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jQuery needs a `ID` to `anchor-jump`, You need to have 4-5 different `anchors` and with `css` hide them behind each other and add `ID` to each `a` and each `div`.

When `click`, remove `anchor`.

*Following code:*

*HTML*

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="nxt-btn">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="nxt-btn">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="nxt-btn">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="nxt-btn">Next</a>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="1">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="2">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="3">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>

<img src="img/divider.png" id="4">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="img/album-img.png" id="album-img">
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.nxt-btn a{display: none}   
.nxt-btn a:first-child{display: block !important;}
```

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nxt-btn').click(function () {
      $(this).remove(); // remove element which is being clicked
    });
});
```